# Add dynamic styles outside header

Tags: javascript, php, css

The situation:
One PHP script can be added unlimited times to a page using includes.
I do not know how many times it well be used
Each instance of the script has it's own settings stored in the database.
When included the settings make the styles for the elements of that instance.
Direct input into the html header is not possible.

My question:
How can I use PHP to my a CSS style tag or external style sheet that only effects the div holding the output of the script.

Example:

```
<div id='instance1'>
    script content with classes
</div>
<div id='instance2'>
    script content with same classes but different setting.
</div>
```

I can define the parent div inside the script so that's not an issue.

Possible solution i don't know if would work:
Using a scoped style stag ()- My understanding is most browsers don't support this yet. Is that true? if not this is a easy and the best way.

Make a php page to out as a CSS then use javascript to add it to the head tag- But I don't know how to pass the settings to the sheet before appending it to the head tag. I don't want to make another call to the database

Use php to make inline styles- Seems simple but would generate a lot redundant code because loops make multiple and many elements that need the same style in each instance of the script. Also could get messy.

Finally, use php to make javascripts to add styles to the class- Very messy and would take a lot of extra lines of code.

So hopefully using a simple option, how would I accomplish this without a messy code?

No code libraries please.

Comment: Styles are styles.  If you're using them correctly then you are using classes to style your data.  There isn't any reason not to have the styles defined in one or more stylesheets that are included whether or not the styles are actually referenced is there?

Comment: `<div class="<?= $class; ?>" ></div>` or `<div style="<?= $style; ?>" ></div>`  nothing wrong with putting inline styles in, it may be easier to see how they are added in later instead of some convoluted approach using javascript to append stuff somewhere or creating all these css files that are dynamic etc. etc.

Comment: With *"messy"* code, do you mean the PHP-Code generating the HTML or the HTML-Code itself? Does your PHP generate full CSS, because you said putting it in the header is not possible. That would be bad practice. Split your CSS down to recurring partials and define them as seperate classes in your header CSS. Your PHP then only puts together the classes needed for each element.

Comment: The styles are stored in the database. The php makes the css after the header is done loading. I cannot define the css before hand so it is not possible to put the styles in the header.